# Flutter Firebase Reading Data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a variable called _memories and I want to update it to the content that is returned from the Firestore database in the .then() and then return it. I know the content is correct in from using the print statement, but neither return statement is returning the updated _memories. It's returning the {'title': 'myTitle'}. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
List getUserMemories() {
  User? currentUser = AuthenticationService().getUser();
  if (currentUser == null) {
    throw Exception('currentUser is null');
  }
  CollectionReference memories = _firestore.collection('memories');
  List _memories = [
    {'title': 'myTitle'}
  ];
  memories
      .where('user_email', isEqualTo: currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) async {
           _memories = await querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
           print("In FirestoreService: $_memories");
           return _memories;
      })
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed to obtain user's memories: $error"));
  
  return _memories;
}
```

Comment: print outside then statement and see if you have values before the final return _memoreis; I guess you dont have to return in then statement just assignment is enough.

Comment: Ideally though, I'd like to return it back to the original screen it was called from so that it could display the data. If that doesn't work, then I can just have the function in the same file and do the assignment instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert `getUserMemories` to an `async` function and use `await` where you call it:

```
List getUserMemories() async {
  User? currentUser = AuthenticationService().getUser();
  if (currentUser == null) {
    throw Exception('currentUser is null');
  }
  CollectionReference memories = _firestore.collection('memories');
  List _memories = [
    {'title': 'myTitle'}
  ];
  try {
    final result = await memories
      .where('user_email', isEqualTo: currentUser.email)
      .get();
    _memories = result.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
    print("In FirestoreService: $_memories");
  } catch (e) {
     print("Failed to obtain user's memories: $e"));
  }  
  return _memories;
}
```